# In PHP/Laravel, package Firebase/JWT token generation secret base64 encoded invalid signature

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, payment-gateway

I had generated a JWT token and tested it on [Jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) with the secret key. When I check the secret base64 encoded then the token show me invalid signature(image added) [image: attached problem]

If I don't check mark the secret base64 encoded then that's a valid signature but I require the secret base64 encoded checked.

Here's the code in my Laravel Controller . I am using [Firebase/JWT](https://packagist.org/packages/firebase/php-jwt) package for PHP .

```
$payload=[
            "enable_auto_capture" => "false",
            "merchant_code" => "234dfrwer8975027a7c746ccb2eaf02bdf19a7ed",
            "merchant_reference" => "PGcfcE20pmm6RaPRBLFxO8T1xnqqE8uK",
            "payment_profile_code" => "",
            "instalment_profile_code" => "",
            "currency" => "MYR",
            "amount" => "242.50",
            "description" => "Flight Ticket KL to Sabah",
            "response_url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/success",
            "additional_reference" => "test",
            "customer" => [
                "customer_id" => "cust_john_5678",
                "customer_name" => "John C",
                "customer_contact_no" => "0134567890",
                "customer_email" => "john_c@paymenthub.com"
            ],
            "billing" => [
                "billing_address_line_1" => "C-7-7, Centum @ Oasis Corporate Park",
                "billing_address_line_2" => "Jalan PJU 1A/3",
                "billing_address_line_3" => "",
                "billing_address_city" => "Petaling Jaya",
                "billing_address_state" => "Selangor",
                "billing_address_postal_code" => "47301",
                "billing_address_country_code" => "MYS"
            ],
        ];
        $apiKey = 'my-api-key';

        // Create a JWT token
        $jwtToken = JWT::encode($payload, $apiKey, 'HS256');
```

How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> When I check the secret base64 encoded then the token show me invalid signature(image added)

The jwt.io tool regenerates the signatures for you, that's why it says it's valid. See how the `HB-ounwggLtTQbxici_CgurcrJGuCrN-lTprD6wxwV8` signature part changes to a new valid signature? You're modifying the secret. You can start typing anything on the right part and the signature will be replaced over the one you supplied. Do not interact with the right part.

It's confusing. But remember the signature above. Now type in "my-api-key" into the box, as you type you'll see that the signature will change, as you type the final y, you'll see that it matches and your signature will be verified.

[image: jwt.io image]

jwt.io is used as a debugging tool, and doesn't have an immediate UI to verify the signature, because it keeps on changing as you change the input and will always say that the signature is valid as soon as you start typing as it recalculates the hash. Again, it's confusing.

Your key is fine. Your library is fine. See this issue as well https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/issues/74